# I don't have groovy installed but my groovy code still works - why?

Tags: groovy, gradle

I have a Java project that has a lot of unit tests written in Groovy.I do not have the GDK installed and it still runs.

The project uses gradle and it has "apply plugin: groovy" in the build script but I was under the impression that it would just use groovyc which is definitely not installed.

How does this work?

Thanks

Comment: You must have a compile time dependency on groovy

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `build.gradle` file, inside the `dependencies` block, you will have a line probably like:

```
compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.1'
```

This line pulls in the specified version of groovy, and the groovy plugin uses it to compile your groovy code

Comment: I looked for that dependency before I posted this and didn't find it, thus my confusion. Now however I noticed that spock was pulling it in. I guess that will do it.

Comment: Yeah, that would do it :-)  For my projects with Groovy in the actual compiled code (not just the tests), I pull in a `compile` version of groovy, and a `testCompile` version of Spock (that matches the Groovy version I'm using) with an exclude on spock's groovy